# SQLite stopped working after upgrade

Tags: 12.04, php, sqlite

As many of you did, I upgraded from Lucid to Precise this week and almost everything seems to work find.

everything except… SQLite, which was working well before but not anymore.

I checked everything: phpinfo(), php.ini, sqlite3.ini.

The `sqlite` command works fine, but when I try to use PHP... *PLOP*, nothing works.

I get the message

```
Fatal error: Class 'SQLiteDatabase' not found in /var/www/test/sqlite/index.php on line 4
```

Line 4 being

```
$db = new SQLiteDatabase('test.sqlite', 0666);
```

Any hint?

---

**edit**

You can see my phpinfo() here: http://pastebin.com/jQ7Bz0GN

The apache log is

```
 * Restarting web server apache2
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
... waiting apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Extensions**

According to [Vendor Specific Database Extensions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.database.vendors.php) page on the PHP site, there are two *SQLite* extensions:

- [SQLite](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite.php)
- [SQLite3](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite3.php)

*SQLite3* extension is a newer replacement of *SQLite*, which [soon will become obsolete](http://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite.requirements.php):

> The SQLite extension is enabled by default as of PHP 5.0.
>   Beginning with PHP 5.4, the SQLite extension is available only via PECL.

**Ubuntu 10.04 vs 12.04**

Now, some practicalities. Let's have a look at default web server configuration that was installed using:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 php5-sqlite
```

*Ubuntu 10.04:*

```
# php --ri sqlite

SQLite

SQLite support => enabled
PECL Module version => 2.0-dev
SQLite Library => 2.8.17
SQLite Encoding => UTF-8

# php --ri sqlite3

sqlite3

SQLite3 support => enabled
SQLite3 module version => 0.7-dev
SQLite Library => 3.6.22
```

*Ubuntu 12.04:*

```
# php --ri sqlite

Extension 'sqlite' not present.

# php --ri sqlite3

sqlite3

SQLite3 support => enabled
SQLite3 module version => 0.7-dev
SQLite Library => 3.7.9
```

So, Ubuntu 12.04 default PHP installation (as of writing this - version 5.3.10) already does not have `sqlite` extension as built in. The output above states that only `sqlite3` extension is present, which came from `php5-sqlite` package.

**Solution**

Pick your evil:

1. Right approach in long term would be to adapt the code to get it working under *SQLite3*. The changes would be minor, but this might involve some unwanted copy-paste-style work on a big amount of files. If this is the case, and *right* is not a right word here, solution 2 is for you.
2. [Install](http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.phpize.php) obsolete extension from [PECL](http://pecl.php.net/).

Comment: Thanks, but that's not it, I've got php5-sqlite installed correctly. Nice try, though!

Comment: Have you defined your own `SQLiteDatabase` class? Asking this because for constructing `SQLiteDatabase` normally is being used this function - `sqlite_open()`. What will happen if you just replace `SQLiteDatabase` with `sqlite_open`?

Comment: Hey! No, I didn't create my own SQLiteDatabase class.

Comment: Then just try to replace `SQLiteDatabase` with `sqlite_open`.

Comment: Doesn't work either: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlite_open()`.

Comment: Well, in this case `php5-sqlite` is present on your system, but `php` won't load it. I would try with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall php5-sqlite` and then `service apache2 restart`. Another thing - can you please post somewhere phpinfo?

Comment: I just tried, it's no good. Is php5-sqlite supposed to appear in the phpinfo? Because it doesn't.

Comment: Yes, all PHP modules should appear there, including `sqlite`. Can you please post it somewhere, along with Apache logs when you restart server via `service apache2 restart`?

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: Updated my answer. In short - your code **should** work. If it's not - restart your server and/or machine. Perhaps there were some misconfiguration issues during/after your system upgrade.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3353/discussion-between-oltarus-and-andrejs-cainikovs)

Comment: Updated. Personally, I would recommend you to go with solution 1. Your first step would be to replace `new SQLiteDatabase('test.sqlite', 0666);` with `new SQLite3('test.sqlite');`, and then resolve all class incompatibilities.

Comment: Is not it possible to remove sqlite an reinstall ?!.

Comment: Thank you, thank you very much. The next error is `Fatal error: Call to undefined method SQLite3::queryExec()`, which is solved with what you said about class compatibility. @AndrejsCainikovs, you truely deserve your reward! Thanks for the long search.

Comment: @Oltarus: I'm glad it helped. Welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Following *Andrejs Cainikovs*' answer and strongly advising you to upgrade the code, here  some examples of what kind of work should be done, when migrating from `SQLiteDatabase` class ([sqlite](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite.php) library) to `SQLite3` class ([SQLite3](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite3.php) library).

For example:

- `SQLiteDatabase` -> `SQLite3`,
- `SQLiteDatabase::unbufferedQuery` -> `SQLite3::query`,
- `SQLiteResult::fetchAll(SQLITE_*)` -> `SQLite3Result::fetchArray(SQLITE3_*)` etc.

As for fetching, in old [SQLite](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite.php) we had:

```
$rowsIMEI = $db->unbufferedQuery($imeiSQL)->fetchAll(SQLITE_ASSOC);

foreach($rowsIMEI as $r)
{
    ...
}
```

While, in new [SQLite3](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite3.php) we should:

```
$rowsIMEI = $db->query($imeiSQL);

while($r = $rowsIMEI->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC))
{
    ...
}
```

Other changes requires similar amount of work, so this shouldn't be a life-time process.

Before you begin, you have to first use a tool like [SQLite Studio](http://sqlitestudio.pl/?act=download) to convert your database file from 2.1 to 3.0. Size can be lowered by even a half, so I think it is something worth fighting for.

Comment: Thank you. I figured it out. The one I still can't understand is why they changed `SQLiteDatabase::singleQuery` to `SQLite3::querySingle`, I'm still mad at them because I have to check every time, I'm unable to remember which is which.

Comment: Oh, I believe that it is not _them_ (the PHP team) who did the change. I think they've just wrote a new set of wrappers over new version of `sqlite` lib. You should go to [sqlite.org](http://sqlite.org/) to blame original SQLite's author! :]

Answer (score 0):

**Solution** (**NOT** for production, just for play):
1. Get "php5-sqlite" deb file from ubuntu11.04 or any other
2. Extract it and find file sqlite.so
-- You can get sqlite.so in other way, for example from Your old system --
3. Put sqlite.so to /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/
4. Add this to php.ini (/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini):

```
extension=sqlite.so
```